I'm encountering difficulties compiling my Vue.js project due to memory constraints when running npm run production or npm run watch
I have recently encountered challenges in compiling my project, which uses Laravel for the backend and Vue.js for the frontend. When running the npm run watch and npm run production commands, the compilation process halts with errors at around 88% or 92%.
The errors that occur are:
•  Memory error
events.js:292
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error [ERR_WORKER_OUT_OF_MEMORY]: Worker terminated due to reaching memory limit
: JS heap out of memory
    at Worker.[kOnExit] (internal/worker.js:238:26)
    at Worker.<computed>.onexit (internal/worker.js:174:20)
Emitted 'error' event on Worker instance at:
    at Worker.[kOnExit] (internal/worker.js:238:12)
    at Worker.<computed>.onexit (internal/worker.js:174:20) {
  code: 'ERR_WORKER_OUT_OF_MEMORY'
}
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! @ production: `mix --production`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the @ production script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional log
ging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\Conecta-05\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2024-06-20T19_5
7_57_367Z-debug.log

•  Clone error
(node:9932) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DataCloneError: Data cannot be clo
ned, out of memory.
    at reportSuccess (C:\xampp\htdocs\crapp\node_modules\jest-worker\build\worke
rs\threadChild.js:70:32)
(Use `node --trace-warnings ...` to show where the warning was created)
(node:9932) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This
error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch
block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). To termina
te the node process on unhandled promise rejection, use the CLI flag `--unhandle
d-rejections=strict` (see https://nodejs.org/api/cli.html#cli_unhandled_rejectio
ns_mode). (rejection id: 1)
(node:9932) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are depre
cated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the
 Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.

I have tried solutions such as node --max-old-space-size=4096, cross-env NODE_OPTIONS=--max-old-space-size=4096, and increasing the npm limit, but to no avail.
The current versions in my project are:
•  Laravel: Laravel Framework 8.83.2
•  npm: 6.14.12
•  Node.js: v14.16.1
OS: Windows 10
Below is my package.json:
{
    "private": true,
    "scripts": {
        "dev": "mix",
        "watch": "mix watch",
        "watch-poll": "mix watch -- --watch-options-poll=1000",
        "hot": "mix watch --hot",
        "production": "mix --production",
        "start": "node --max-old-space-size=4096 public/assets/js/app.js"
    },
    "devDependencies": {
        "babel-eslint": "^8.2.6",
        "cross-env": "^5.2.1",
        "eslint-config-prettier": "^6.15.0",
        "eslint-loader": "^3.0.4",
        "eslint-plugin-prettier": "^3.3.0",
        "eslint-plugin-vue": "^4.7.1",
        "laravel-mix": "^6.0.49",
        "postcss": "^8.4.16",
        "prettier": "^2.7.1",
        "resolve-url-loader": "3.1.0",
        "sass": "^1.54.9",
        "sass-loader": "^8.0.2",
        "tailwindcss-plugins": "^0.3.0",
        "vue-template-compiler": "^2.7.10",
        "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0"
    },
    "dependencies": {
        "@banyinbanying/city-table": "^1.0.5",
        "@bytefury/spacewind": "^0.5.0",
        "@mathieustan/vue-datepicker": "^0.2.11",
        "@vue-hero-icons/outline": "^1.6.3",
        "@vue-hero-icons/solid": "^1.6.3",
        "axios": "^0.21.1",
        "chart.js": "^2.7.3",
        "guid": "0.0.12",
        "litepie-datepicker": "^1.0.14",
        "lodash": "^4.17.13",
        "moment": "^2.29.4",
        "node-sass": "^4.14.1",
        "quill": "^1.3.6",
        "sweet-modal-vue": "^2.0.0",
        "sweetalert": "^2.1.2",
        "tailwindcss": "^2.0.1",
        "toastr": "^2.1.4",
        "v-tooltip": "^2.0.2",
        "vue": "^2.7.10",
        "vue-csv-import": "^2.3.4",
        "vue-ctk-date-time-picker": "^2.5.0",
        "vue-i18n": "^8.27.2",
        "vue-json-csv": "^1.2.12",
        "vue-loader": "^15.10.0",
        "vue-router": "2.7.0",
        "vue-sweetalert2": "^5.0.5",
        "vue-tailwind-color-picker": "^1.0.6",
        "vue2-daterange-picker": "^0.6.8",
        "vue2-transitions": "^0.3.0",
        "vuedraggable": "^2.24.2",
        "vuelidate": "^0.7.7",
        "vuex": "^3.0.1"
    }
}

The most frustrating aspect is that I've monitored my PC's memory usage, and even with up to 4GB of RAM available, the compilation process still comes to a halt.

